# Passport local strategy signup succeeds but does not redirect

Tags: node.js, promise, passport.js, passport-local

I implemented a custom local strategy with promises, but the function does not redirect even though a new user is created in the database.

Here is my database handler:

```
export function saveUser(email, password) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    database
      .select('*')
      .from('user')
      .where({ email })
      .then(results => {
        const user = results[0];
        if (user) {
          console.log('found matching username');
          return reject(new Error('Email already taken'));
        } else {
          bcrypt
          .hash(password, SALT_ROUNDS)
          .then(hash => {
            // TODO: Require more information on initial signup?
            const newUser = {
              email,
              date_of_birth: new Date(),
              first_name: 'First',
              last_name: 'Last',
              phone_number: '45555555',
              hashed_password: hash,
            };
            database
            .insert(newUser, 'id')
            .into('user')
            .then(id => {
              newUser.id = id[0];
              console.log('new user successfully created');
              return resolve(null, newUser);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log('database insertion error', error);
              return reject(error);
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log('hashing error', error);
            return reject(error);
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('database email search error', error);
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
passport.use(
  'local-signup',
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: 'email',
      passwordField: 'password',
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    (req, email, password, done) => {
      saveUser(email, password)
        .then(user => done(null, user))
        .catch(error => done(null, false, error));
    },
  ),
);
```

Route that handles signups:

```
router.post('/register', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
  successRedirect: '/dashboard', // redirect to the secure profile section
  failureRedirect: '/register', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
}));
```

When I test the API using Postman, then a new user is successfully created and "new user successfully created" is printed out, but the user is still redirected to the failureRedirect route.

Are you able to spot my error?

Comment: Add the function that handles your sign-up route to your question, that's where the redirection is supposed to happen.
Also, add logs to your code and see what is the was last logged. that will be the place to focus on.

Comment: I added the router part. There is no error thrown so no log traces.

Comment: Try changing the route like so:


router.post('/register', function (req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('local-login', function (err, user, info) {
        //log err, user, info
    });
});

Do you reach that callback? do you see an error/ user there?
Also, did you make sure code executes completely? if not -> add some logs and see where it stops

Comment: Also, change  your catch function to call the done function like this: done(err) - this is an error callback call convention which I assume passport expects

Comment: Kudos to your debugging method. If you look closely then I returned `resolve(null, newUser);` and in this way the user in the controller is always undefined. Many thanks my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Simple copy-paste typo:

`return resolve(null, newUser);` => `return resolve(newUser);`